# Extension of a metric defined on a closed subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X$ is any metrizable space, $A$ is a closed subset of $X$. 
Let $d$ be a compatible metric on $A$ 
then $d$ can be extended to a compatible metric on $X$.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Any reason you still did not accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I cite (with a correction) the beginning of my paper “On Extension of (Pseudo-)Metrics from Subgroup of Topological Group onto the Group”:

“The problem of extensions of functions from subobjects to objects in 
various categories was considered by many authors. The classic 
Tietze-Urysohn theorem on extensions of functions from a closed subspace of
a topological space and its generalizations belong to the known results.
Hausdorff [3] showed that every metric from a closed subspace of
a metrizable space can be extended onto the space. Isbell [4, Lemma 1.4] showed that every bounded uniformly continuous pseudometric on a subspace of a uniform space can be extended to a bounded uniformly continuous pseudometric on the whole space. The linear operators extending metrics from a closed subspace of a metrizable space onto the space were considered in, e.g.,
[2,6]”.

*References*

[2] Bessaga C., *Functional analytic aspects of geometry. Linear extending of metrics and related problems*, in: *Progress of Functional
Analysis*, Proc. Peniscola Meeting 1990 on the 60th birthday of Professor M. Valdivia, North-Holland, Amsterdam (1992) 247-257.

[3] Hausdorff F. *Erweiterung einer Homömorpie*, - Fund. Math., **16** (1930) 353-360.

[4] Isbell J.R. *[On finite-dimensional uniform spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039456)*, - Pacific
J. of Math., **9** (1959) 107-121.

[6] Zarichnyi M., *Regular Linear Operators Extending Metrics: a Short Proof*,
Bull. Pol. Ac.:Math., **44** (1996) 267-269.

Comment: Re :"Isbell [4]  showed that..."    This doesn't look right.What if the subspace is empty? Not all uniform space are  metrizable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks. I corrected it and added a link to the paper.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Hello! I was wondering the following. Let X be a uniform space and A dense subspace (with the uniform topology). Suppose that A has a (bounded) metric $d$. Is it possible to extend it to a metric on X? .....Not a pseudo-metric but a metric. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexRavsky To be precise, $d$ is uniformly continuous on A.

Comment: @Curious If the extension should be uniformly continuous then the answer can be negative. Indeed, let $X$ be the unit segment $[0,1]$ endowed with the usual uniformity, $A=(0,1)$ and $d(x,y)=|e^{2\pi x}- e^{2\pi y}|$. Then $d$ is uniformly continuous on $A\times A$, but $\bar d(0,1)=0$ for any continuous extension $\bar d$ of $d$ to $X^2$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, thanks :)